# How to create .apk files for Android?

Tags: android, apk

I tried right clicking on my project (in Eclipse) android tools->Export unsigned application package.

I then moved to .apk file to my Samsung Galaxi S device and tried to install it,
I got a message saying the app was not installed.

Did I do something wrong in creating the .apk (what could be the problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the application with debug key then you need device driver(Kies in your case) installed on your development machine. Then attach your device to your machine through USB port. Close emulator and run your Android application on your device using Eclipse. The signing procedure mentioned in previous answers is mandatory only when you are uploading your application on Android Market.

Comment: How can I run my Android application on my device with eclipse ?

Comment: As i said u need Device drivers installed on ur development machine. As per my knowledge Kies is the driver for sansung devices.

Comment: You need to enable USB debugging on the phone itself (by starting the Settings application and selecting Applications > Development > USB Debugging), install the Android USB device driver if you haven’t already (Windows only), and then plug the phone into your computer using the USB cable that came with the phone. Close the emulator window if it’s already open. As long as the phone is plugged in, Eclipse will load and run applications on the phone instead. You need to right-click the project and select Run As > Android Application...huh.......enf

Answer (score 2):

Check this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should Export signed Apk file:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html